# Developed 35mm Film Green Tinted instead of Orange

Tags: film, 35mm, developing

I recently started shooting using two old 35 mm film cameras (Minolta 7s and Olympus OM-G). Since all labs have been closed, I've been developing film at home using first Cinestill, then Arista's developing kits, and scanning using the Epson V-600.

Many of my photos have been coming out blue- or green-tinted (photo 1), and the Epson software has been able to correct some of them (photo 2), but not all.

[image: Blue Tinted photo-Software was not able to color correct]
[image: Epson color corrected photo]

I noticed that the last few photos in many of the rolls came out okay--i.e. not needing *any* color correction. When I looked at the film, I saw that that entire section of the roll was tinted a different color. I realized then that instead of being tinted orange, like most developed film should be, most of my film had been coming out greenish-blueish. The pictures where the film was tinted orange came out wonderfully, while those with an overall greenish hue ended up having the same hue.

[image: discolored sections of film]

Any idea what I could be doing wrong in the development process that the film comes out the wrong color in the end? I had very few rolls (maybe 3/15) come out the correct orange color, but otherwise they're all off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the color mask of this 135 film dark blue-green?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99739/why-is-the-color-mask-of-this-135-film-dark-blue-green)

Comment: What exact film(s) are you using ?  And is it new stock or old stock ?

Comment: All the film I've been using is new stock. Mainly Fujifilm 400, Kodak Gold 400, and some Kodak Portra 800

Comment: How are you controlling temperature? How old is the film, and how was it stored?

Answer (score 1):

The film is light struck.  The cyan/green coloration is because the yellow-forming and cyan-forming layers of the film are the first two at the surface, while the (Fuji only) green-forming and red-forming are below them, so a faint light falling on the surface of the film will preferentially expose those layers (also, the cyan dye is much stronger, visually, than yellow, so it'll show more).

The image areas in the portion of the roll that's affected likely also have a cast that will scan or print as yellow/orange.  If the unaffected frames are at the end of the roll, there may have been an accident with the back of the camera that exposed only the film that was already out of the cassette.  Since this is happening with a majority of your films, you might also look for things like a wristwatch with a light that can come on automatically (in the changing bag), pulling your arms out of the bag sleeves while the film is open, or other sources of small amounts of light while you're loading the film into the processing tank.